# why angular 17 ssr setInterval not working

Tags: angular, server-side-rendering, angular-ssr

when i use setInterval or setTimeOut my app dont run and cant get build ?
how i can solve this problem.

```
startAutoIncrement() 
this.intervalId = setInterval(() => {
  this.increment();`your text`
}, 1000);
```

Answer (score 0):

When you use `setInterval` you app stay in an unstable state.

When you use SSR, the generated HTML is only sent to the client once the app become stable for the first time.